# combine numpy arrays in pandas such that we have the same column length

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

saying I have the following numpy arrays:

```
a = np.array([1,2,3])
b = np.array([2,3,4])
c = np.array([1,2,4])
```

And I would like to have a panda dataframe with these three arrays as columns arranged in this way:

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Nan | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 3 | Nan |
| Nan | 4 | 4 |

Could you please suggest me a way to do this efficiently?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Convert the arrays to pandas series with partially overlapping index then concat all the series along axis=1

```
pd.concat([pd.Series(x, index=x) for x in (a, b, c)], axis=1)
```

---

```
     0    1    2
1  1.0  NaN  1.0
2  2.0  2.0  2.0
3  3.0  3.0  NaN
4  NaN  4.0  4.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert the arrays to Series with themselves as index to benefit from index alignment, and [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
dic = {'A': a, 'B': b, 'C': c}

df = pd.concat({k: pd.Series(x, index=x)
                for k, x in dic.items()}, 
               axis=1)
```

Output:

```
     A    B    C
1  1.0  NaN  1.0
2  2.0  2.0  2.0
3  3.0  3.0  NaN
4  NaN  4.0  4.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution, using `numpy broadcasting`:

```
v = np.arange(np.min([a, b, c]), np.max([a, b, c])+1)
m = (v == np.stack([a[:, None], b[:, None], c[:, None]])).any(axis=1)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.tile(v[:, None], 3), columns=list('abc'))
df.where(m.T)
```

Output:

```
     a    b    c
0  1.0  NaN  1.0
1  2.0  2.0  2.0
2  3.0  3.0  NaN
3  NaN  4.0  4.0
```